# Функция StretchDIBits и структура BITMAINFO и непонятный параметр RGBQUAD

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот в WinApi есть структура BITMAPINFO :https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfo

Эта структура используется, как один из входных параметров для функции отображения изображения в окне StretchDIBits :https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchdibits

```
int StretchDIBits(
  [in] HDC              hdc,
  [in] int              xDest,
  [in] int              yDest,
  [in] int              DestWidth,
  [in] int              DestHeight,
  [in] int              xSrc,
  [in] int              ySrc,
  [in] int              SrcWidth,
  [in] int              SrcHeight,
  [in] const VOID       *lpBits,
  [in] const BITMAPINFO *lpbmi,
  [in] UINT             iUsage,
  [in] DWORD            rop
);


BITMAPINFO {
  BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
  RGBQUAD          bmiColors[1];
}
```

Вот чего я не могу понять: что за параметр RGBQUAD в структуре BITMAPINFO ?
Из документации следует, что:

> RGBQUAD - это Элементы массива, составляющие таблицу цветов.

Я не совсем могу понять, что это такое. Разве массив цветов, то есть сам буфер пикселей не подается отдельно в функцию рисования StretchDIBits - это параметр lpBits:

> Указатель на биты изображения, которые хранятся в виде массива байтов.

Кто нибудь может пожалуйста подсказать, как все таки нужно заполнить параметр RGBQUAD структуры BITMAPINFO ?

Comment: таблицу цветов - это имеется ввиду палитру, при использовании которой пиксели хранят не цвет, а индекс

Comment: Если палитра не нужна (формат RGB, RGBA), то bmiColors не используется. Для изображения с палитрой к концу BITMAPINFO подцепляется требуемое количество элементов RGBQUAD.

Comment: @Alex F, Спасибо, но, как указать, что мне не нужно использовать параметр RGBQUAD ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchdibits `iUsage = DIB_RGB_COLORS`